# How do I handle the error: 'Not allowed to start service Intent without permission' where the service belongs to another application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-permissions

I am trying to run a service (RUN_SYNC) from my android application, the service belongs to another application already installed on my android device, I am currently just testing the service before use. I added the relevant permissions to my manifest as well.

### Here is my application's code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button syncButton = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        syncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                        "org.opendatakit.services",
                        "org.opendatakit.services.sync.service.OdkSyncService"));
                startService(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.opendatakit.webkitserver.RUN_WEBSERVER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.opendatakit.database.RUN_DATABASE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.opendatakit.sync.RUN_SYNC" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the service declaration and permission declaration in the AndroidManifest.xml of the application (ODK-X Services) which originally declared the service (the package is "org.opendatakit.services">):

```
<service android:name=".sync.service.OdkSyncService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":sync"
    android:permission="org.opendatakit.sync.RUN_SYNC" >
</service>
    
<permission android:name="org.opendatakit.sync.RUN_SYNC"
            android:label="@string/sync_launch_permission"
            android:permissionGroup="org.opendatakit.services.permissions"
            android:protectionLevel="signature">
</permission>
```

### This is the error:

```
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 1423
    java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=org.opendatakit.services/.sync.service.OdkSyncService } without permission org.opendatakit.sync.RUN_SYNC
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1381)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1358)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:613)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5648)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22442)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

**I checked using adb shell command if the permissions I am trying to use exist in my android device- they do. I am not permitted to edit the second application's code but it should not matter since it exports the service (export set to true). I read many posts but none of the suggestions (copying all permissions of the second application, ordering permissions for dependencies, and checking the supported SDK which is 16 in my case, not 23) helped. It will really help me if someone could look this over and point out where I am going wrong. Thank you!**

Comment: You may need to somehow ensure that the app with the `<permission>` element is installed before the app with the corresponding `<uses-permission>` element. Also, this is a `signature` permission, so the two apps have to be signed by the same signing key.

Comment: Could you please explain more about how to sign an app using signing key and how to get the other app's signing key?

Comment: its a bit lengthy process so I suggest you take a look here : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing @ApurvaBhargava

Comment: I only have access to the .RSA of the other application (I am not its owner, it is just open source), how do I convert it to jks (javakeystore) since that is what is required in the above documentation?

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. Your response was helpful.